# Rust: Trait RangeBounds cannot be made into an object

Tags: rust, trait-objects

I sumbled upon a problem while trying out Rust, that might point to a bigger non understanding of its concepts on my part.

My goal is to programm a variant of Conway's Game of Life. I want the values when cells are created or stay alive not to be hard coded, but within a struct. My first attempt was to create a struct

```rust
use std::ops::Range;

struct Rules {
    be_born: Range<usize>,
    stay_alive: Range<usize>,
}

impl Rules {
  pub fn new(be_born: Range<usize>, stay_alive: Range<usize>) -> Rules {
    Rules { be_born, stay_alive }
  }
}

let rules = Rules::new(2..4, 3..6);
```

This object is later used within the algorithm that iterates over all the cells. It works fine, until I also want to allow other kind of Ranges during creation like for example RangeTo (2..=3).

I know I could rewrite the `struct Rules` to be generic.

```rust
use std::ops::RangeBounds;

struct Rules<BR: RangeBounds<usize>, AR: RangeBounds<usize>> {
    be_born: BR,
    stay_alive: AR,
}
```

This in turn would force me to make all the algorithms I use to be generic as well. This seems to be quite a lot of overhead just to include two simple ranges.

On the other hand none of my attempts to include variables of type `RangeBounds` directly into my struct succeeded. I tried `&dyn RangeBounds<usize>` or `Box<&dyn RangeBounds<usize>>`, just to always get the error E0038 that I cannot make this trait into an object.

Is there any other way to get this done, or is there some other feasable way I do not see?

Thank you in advance for all your hints.

Comment: Instead of using RangeBounds as a type, try using it as a bound: `struct Rules<T: RangeBounds> {be_born: T, stay_alive: T}`

Comment: @IvanC You can't. It needs to have a generic type parameter, either as another generic parameter of struct `Rules` -which involves in using `PhantomData`- or as an const parameter like `usize`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a broad answer, we need to know how exactly you are iterating over `be_born` and `stay_alive` fields. But for solving the problem you point out that you want to use different kind of ranges, the easiest way is specifying that `be_born` and `stay_alive` fields are both an `Iterable` that returns `usize` when iterated over, aka `Iterator<Item=usize>`:

```rust
struct Rules<T, U> 
where
    T: Iterator<Item=usize>,
    U: Iterator<Item=usize>
{
    be_born: T,
    stay_alive: U,
}

impl<T, U> Rules<T, U>
where
    T: Iterator<Item=usize>,
    U: Iterator<Item=usize>
{
    pub fn new(be_born: T, stay_alive: U) -> Self {
        Self { be_born, stay_alive }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let rule = Rules::new(2..4, 3..6);
    let other_rule = Rules::new(2..=4, 3..=6);
    let another_rule = Rules::new(2..=4, 3..6);

    for x in rule.be_born {
        println!("born: {}", x);
    }
    for y in rule.stay_alive {
        println!("alive: {}", y);
    }
}
```

This will also allow you to assign non-range but iterable types to `be_born` and `stay_alive` fields. If you want to restrict yourself to range types only, you can replace every `Iterator<Item=usize>` in the code with `Iterator<Item=usize> + RangeBounds<usize>`, which means "a type which both implements `Iterator<Item=usize>` and `RangeBounds<usize>`".

For further usage of `Iterator` trait, see [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-02-iterators.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was not quite what I was looking for, but implictly you gave the answer I needed: I was on the total wrong track that I could store the trait object while avoiding Generics. For my actual problem I needed to rethink how I structure the program. So thank you for putting me back on the right track.

Comment: @RüdigerLudwig You are welcome. Use dynamic trait objects only when you can't do what you want using generics, generics are much easier to deal with and often provide a faster runtime.